# Compute Statistics using Analyse statement in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to compute statistics for Hive table using Spark SQL context.

**Spark Version : 1.6.3**

```
sqlContext.sql("ANALYZE TABLE sample PARTITION (company='aaa', market='aab',pdate='2019-01-10') COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS")
```

I am getting the below error but I am able to execute the same query in Hive.

**Error:**

```
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. Could not initialize class com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes
```

When I try to run as below I am facing error as **"Partition not found"**

```
sqlContext.sql("ANALYZE TABLE sample PARTITION (company='aaa', market='aab',pdate='2019-01-10') COMPUTE STATISTICS")
```

**Error:**

```
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10006]: Line 1:56 Partition not found ''2019-01-10''
```

Please let me know on how to rectify the same.

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below queries

```
sqlContext.sql("ANALYZE TABLE sample COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS col1 [, col2, ...]")

sqlContext.sql("ANALYZE TABLE sample COMPUTE STATISTICS [NOSCAN]")
```

Please check https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/analyze-table.html for more info.

Comment: @v.rajan Still facing same issue?